# How to calculate areas of land cover from a File System Raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, raster-calculator, area, catchment-area

I am using ArcMap 10.2.  I have a raster displaying land cover.  I also have a shapefile of polygons overlaid on top.  I would like to calculate the areas of different land covers within the polygons.

I have included a picture to help convey my problem.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the Spatial Analyst extension available, I think that the [Tabulate Area tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/tabulate-area.htm) will do what you're looking for. If you specify your polygon feature class/shapefile as the "Input feature zone data", your "zone field" as anything uniquely identifying the polygons, and your land cover raster as the "Input raster".

This will generate a table with the area of each category in the raster represented in the units of the raster. Note in my example below I had only selected two features in the counties dataset to reduce processing time, so it's worth remembering that having something selected in the "Input feature zone data" class will limit processing to just that subset.

[image: Tabulate Area with a counties polygon dataset and a land cover raster]

[image: Output of the tool]

Comment: GREAT! Thanks.  Where do you get your land cover from?

Comment: Did you use the nlcd_2011 Landcover data? If so how did you set up you classifications (ie. DEVELOPED_OPEN SPACE etc.)?

Comment: Hi, @Matt . I believe I just pulled the 2011 data from the USGS (National Map) and used the LAND_COVER field. I've had the data laying around unused for a while so I can't offer a lot more specifics than that unfortunately.

Comment: were you able to find a shapefile?